# Save app data on Android/iOS using Haxe/OpenFL

Tags: android, ios, haxe, openfl

So, I've created a Haxe function (using the OpenFL library) that saves text and image data to the game's folder on desktop targets. A little while ago, however, I was notified [in this thread](http://community.stencyl.com/index.php/topic,35620.msg224122#msg224122) that the function would not work on mobile targets. The same user, **thiagojabur**, also gave me a solution (scroll down in the same thread). My main problem is that I don't have a mobile device myself that I can test on (I have a Galaxy Tab4, but I haven't gotten it working with my Haxe projects). Rather than send 100 versions to someone who *can* test it, I've decided to ask my questions here.

The goal is to save the data into a folder with the game's App ID. For instance, if the App ID is `com.potato.potatogame`, then the data will be saved (on Android) in the application storage directory, in the folder `/Android/data/com.potato.potatogame/`. I believe I can get the first part of the path using `openfl.utils.SystemPath.applicationStorageDirectory()`, but I'm stuck on how to get the App ID. Does anyone know of a function which can do so?

Alternatively, I may be misunderstanding a part of the code. From the way **thiagojabur** used the code, it would seem that `SystemPath.userDirectory()` returns `"/Android/data/com.potato.potatogame"` on Android. Is this correct, or would I still need to build the path manually?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In one of my apps using OpenFL in legacy mode I saved an images using following code:

```
static var IMAGES_PATH:String = SystemPath.documentsDirectory + "/MyAppName/";

public function saveImage() 
{
    var filename:String = IMAGES_PATH + name + ".png";

    try {
        if(!FileSystem.exists(IMAGES_PATH)) {
            FileSystem.createDirectory(IMAGES_PATH);
        }
        File.saveBytes(filename, app.canvas.bitmap.encode("png"));
    } 
    catch(e:Dynamic) {
        trace(e);
    }
}
```

With modern non-legacy code, I guess the path getting should be changed to `lime.system.System.applicationStorageDirectory`

Also if you still need to get the App ID, it can be achieved by `Application.current.config.packageName`